# wordpress the permalink action hook?

Tags: wordpress, action, hook, permalinks

Is there any action hook for wordpress the_permalink ?
For example, whenever the the_permalink function is triggered, I need to write a plugin that will try to edit the URL according to my needs, and then return the edited URL that will be echoed.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I believe this may be what you're looking for: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: @AndyWarren that's what I was search for. Thanks for helping... :-)

Comment: @AndyWarren can you please help me about another permalink issue here? Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283030/wordpress-i-removed-parent-slug-from-url-but-wordpress-redirects-and-include-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and let me post in reply so that other members can get help. the_permalink() wordpress functions is used for this purpose. I used this and solve my problem. Thanks to @AndyWarren.

Here is the function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink