# Wordpress: I Removed Parent Slug from URL but wordpress redirects and include parent slug again

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, parent, slug

I have successfully removed the parent slug from URL and have reduced the URL from:

```
http://myexp.uphero.com/sample-page/child-sample-page/
```

to

```
http://myexp.uphero.com/child-sample-pagee/
```

This is a test wordpress website for testing purposes.
But when I visit the newly reduced URL, the old URL (with parent slug) appears again in the browser's URL bar. Please help me, why this it is including the parent slug again in the URL?
I have search around the web but didn't find solution.
Also, I have written the following rewrite rule for the reduced URL

```
^child-sample-pagee/?$' => '/index.php?pagename=child-sample-page'
```

The rewrite rule also works well, without any problem. Just visit the above newly created reduced link, and you will see the actual problem. Waiting for response and solution.

Comment: Why does it need to be a child page?  It appears as though you just want it to have a top level permalink, so why not just make it a top level page?

Comment: @AndyWarren my client who has assignment me this task to do cannot make it top level. In admin panel, they want it to see as child level in order to organize the pages. But in permalinks, he wants the permalinks to shorten. I have successfully shortened the permalinks, but the automatic redirection is the problem now and still can't find the solution. Is there any solution for this?